# automatic t.timestamps after rails generate model, can I manually remove this in the migration file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, twitter-oauth

I ran `rails generate model XXXX user_id:integer stream_url:text` etc

I noticed that `t.timestamps` was part of the migration file. Can I manually remove this line without causing any problems in the future?

I searched and couldn't find an answer. I just wanted to check in advance before it causes issues down the line.

I'm trying to follow the steps in this link http://ckdake.com/content/2010/posting-to-twitter-from-a-ruby-on-rails-app.html to use the twitter gem

Answer (score 8):

Use  `rails g model MyModel --no-timestamps`

More info with `rails g model --help`

Answer (score 3):

In rails migration logic t.timestamp is just add two colums **created_at, updated_at**. Exactly this two columns are required when you forming the model query based on the time created, updated.

If you are not going to use this types of query in future, absolutely you can ignore it.

Comment: The OP asked specifically if these columns could be removed without consequence (the same question I had which led me to this post), not whether it was ok to ignore them.  Also, according to pinouchon's answer below, your statement that these two columns are required is inaccurate.